# Set background of include layout programmatically

Tags: android, xml

I have fragment and fragment_layout which include some common layout via include tag,when I try to set the background color for included layout programmatically that color is shown properly on first launch of fragment but on subsequent launch all the child views of fragment_layout show the programmatically set color.I had tested it in Samsung-SGH-I467 with Android Version 4.1.2.

DummyFragment.java

```
    public class DummyFragment extends Fragment {


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_details,container,false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            setSiteAndPhoneText();
            GridView containerAttributes = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.container_attributes_grid);

            List<Map.Entry<String, String>> dataForContainer = getDummyDataForContainer();
            if (dataForContainer != null) {
                ContainerAttributeGridAdapter adapter = new ContainerAttributeGridAdapter(this.getActivity(),
                        dataForContainer);
                containerAttributes.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }


        private void setSiteAndPhoneText() {
            // Set Instructions.

            View instructionHolder = getView().findViewById(R.id.includelayout3);
            TextView instructionHeader = (TextView) instructionHolder.findViewById(R.id.attributerowheader);
           instructionHeader.setText("ABC");
            TextView instructionContent = (TextView) instructionHolder.findViewById(R.id.atributerowcontent);
            instructionContent.setText("PQR");


            // Set Contact.
            View contactHolder = getView().findViewById(R.id.includelayout2);
            TextView contactHeader = (TextView) contactHolder.findViewById(R.id.attributerowheader);
            contactHeader.setText("XYZ");
            TextView contactDetails = (TextView) contactHolder.findViewById(R.id.atributerowcontent);
            contactDetails.setText("MNP");
            //contactHolder.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);


            // Set CustomerDetails
            View customerDetailsHolder = getView().findViewById(R.id.includelayout1);
            TextView customerDetailsText = (TextView) customerDetailsHolder.findViewById(R.id.atributerowcontent);
            TextView customerNameText = (TextView) customerDetailsHolder.findViewById(R.id.attributerowheader);

customerDetailsHolder.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(100);
            customerNameText.setText("DDDDD");
            customerDetailsText.setText("ddddddmmmmm");

        }

        private List<Map.Entry<String, String>> getDummyDataForContainer() {
            List<Map.Entry<String, String>> containerAttributesList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, String>>();
            Map.Entry<String, String> size = new ContainerAttributes<String, String>("Size", "10");
            Map.Entry<String, String> type = new ContainerAttributes<String, String>("Type", "10");
            Map.Entry<String, String> truck = new ContainerAttributes<String, String>("Truck", "10");
            Map.Entry<String, String> material = new ContainerAttributes<String, String>("Material", "10");
            Map.Entry<String, String> wheels = new ContainerAttributes<String, String>("Wheels", "10");
            Map.Entry<String, String> locks = new ContainerAttributes<String, String>("Locks", "10");
            Map.Entry<String, String> lids = new ContainerAttributes<String, String>("Lids", "10");
            Map.Entry<String, String> others = new ContainerAttributes<String, String>("Others", "10");

            containerAttributesList.add(size);
            containerAttributesList.add(type);
            containerAttributesList.add(truck);
            containerAttributesList.add(material);
            containerAttributesList.add(wheels);
            containerAttributesList.add(locks);
            containerAttributesList.add(lids);
            containerAttributesList.add(others);

            return containerAttributesList;

        }
    }
```

dummy_details.xml

Included Relative layout without any background.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="1dp" >

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/includelayout1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    layout="@layout/include_layout_details" />

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/container_attributes_grid"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/includelayout1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="#E2E2E2"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:numColumns="4"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
                </GridView>

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/includelayout2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_above="@id/container_attributes_grid"
                    layout="@layout/include_layout_details" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/includelayout3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/container_attributes_grid"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    layout="@layout/include_layout_details" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

include_layout_details.xml

Included linearlayout with background as E2E2E2

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#E2E2E2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/attributerowheader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/atributerowcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"

            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Note: I had not included GridAdapter files,but GridAdapter is using below file for row display.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/detailsrowheader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
       />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/detailsrowcontent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

After first launch it is showing proper color to all the `<include>` view but after next launch for fragment it is showing RED color in all the `<include>` view as well as gridview.

Code is working fine in Nexus 5 with 6.0 but while testing it with 4.1.2 Samsung Tab it is not working.

Comment: Are you saying that each child view of your GridView is also becoming red?

Comment: Yes GridView child as well as all the include tag,but on second launch onwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the background of included layout as well as its child views background as `android:background="#00000000"` this will make it transparent
.

Then in your fragment once you get the reference of the view ; you could specify the background color at runtime by simply writing

```
view1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); //your color choice
view2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Hope this helps.